# Double radio button selection bug AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of radio buttons, when I load my app the first radio is selected by default, so if I go to the second radio I can see different information in an HTML table, then If I change the values of my filters and then make a request I want the radio buttons refresh again and have the default selected but that is no happening, the second radio button is selected.

```
    <div class="radio" ng-init="topTable='topCategory'">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="topTable" value="topCategory" ng-change="updateTotals('topCategory')">TY Top 30 Categories</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="topTable" value="topSupplier" ng-change="updateTotals('topSupplier')">TY Top 10 Suppliers</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="topTable" value="topBrand" ng-change="updateTotals('topBrand')">TY Top 10 Brands</label>
    </div>
```

The ng-init make the first radio to be selected I also used a function like this

```
    function topRadios() {
        $scope.topTable = "topCategory";

    }
```

and my ng-init was "ng-init="topRadios()";

I dont know if I need to use ng-value instead of value or if I need to add some logic to my controller or what.

Any help on this?

Comment: Are you attempting to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/u9vm0ryx/2/

Comment: @BuddhistBeast you should submit it as an answer

Comment: Thanks, it works!! @BuddhistBeast

Could you put it as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just recall the function like so:

```
 <button ng-click="triggerTable()" type="button">Refresh</button>
```

And the corresponding function:

```
$scope.triggerTable = function() {
    $scope.topTable = "topCategory";
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u9vm0ryx/3/)